# How we can purchase an already owned item from Google Play?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am using in-app version 3 in my app. I want to purchase an already owned item from play store. But I saw that managed products can be purchased only once per user account and in Version 3, all in-app products are managed. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consume the in-app product within your app by sending a `consumePurchase` call. Afterwards the item can be purchased again. See https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#consume for details.

Comment: where we should use this after buying the product or while deleting the existing ?

Comment: You should send `consumePurchase` after you have persisted the information that the purchase has been made. For example if your app is an online game and your in-app purchase is "500 gamecoins" you should send `consumePurchase` once the game server has add 500 to the gamecoin balance.

Comment: Is there any limit to use a product like this? i mean maximum 50 purchase or something like that?

Comment: I haven't seen any documented limit on the number of times an in-app product can be purchased and consumed. Nor did I see any report about such a limit. Of course if your in-app product is expensive the user might go bancrupt eventually. ;)

Comment: I implemented that , but it shows item already owned message .is there any other reason for this?

Comment: Do you get a SUCCESS response for your consumption request?